# Get a Players Next Rank in database - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'am using the Halo 5 API, and I'm trying to get a players total Progress till their next rank. In order to do that, one of the steps is I have to get a players **next rank**. *From there on I can get the start Xp of that rank.*

I know how to get a players current rank with its Start XP. What I cant figure out is how to get the next rank ( or row ) from the database.

This is how my function is set up right now:

```
 public function currentProgressRank($playerArenaStats) {

        // Get a players current xp and rank from API JSON array
        $PlayersRankXP = $playerArenaStats->Results[0]->Result->Xp;
        $PlayersRank = $playerArenaStats->Results[0]->Result->SpartanRank;

        // Get a Players current Rank from Database by comparing a players rank from API to a rank ID from Database
        $GetStartXp = Ranks::where('rank_id', '=', $PlayersRank)->get();


        // Do a foreach loop, and get the start XP into the current rank
        foreach ($GetStartXp as $XP) {
            $GetStart = $XP->startXp;
        }


        // Need to get Start Xp for the Players next rank here....

    }
```

*I know there is the **next()** method, but how would I implement that into a laravel eloquent search*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, like this:

```
        // Get the start Xp of next rank for Player
        $GetStartXpOfNextRank = Ranks::where('rank_id', '=', $PlayersRank + 1)->get();

        foreach ($GetStartXpOfNextRank as $XPNext) {
            $GetStartXPNext = $XPNext->startXp;
        }
```